# How to get the list append right with if-elif?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

The following code ---

```
lu,area = ([],)*2
row = [10,20]
column = [1,2]

for x in row:
  for y in column:
            if y==1:
                lu.append(y)
                print(lu)
                print(area)
                
            elif y==2:
                area.append(y)
                print(lu)
                print(area)
```

is printing ---

```
[1]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

But, the desired outcome is ---

```
[1]
[]
[1]
[2]
[1, 1]
[2]
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
```

Why are both lists being appended together inspite of the if-elif logic?

Thanks for taking the time out to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very first line, `lu,area = ([],)*2`, is too cute for its own good. It's equivalent to `lu = area = []`, both variables refer to the same (initially empty) list object. When you later start appending to the list, it doesn't matter which variable name you use for it, all the values end up together.

What you probably want is `lu, area = [], []`, which binds the variables to separate empty lists. You might even want to do the assignments on separate lines, to keep things extra clear:

```
lu = []
area = []
```

Comment: Lol. I never thought the problem lies with the cute initialization. Thanks for helping out @Blckknght!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the first line where you wrote `lu,area = ([],)*2`
When you use the `*` operator in such a way, python creates multiple copies that reference the same object. Thus when you change its value using either variable, it makes changes to the same object.

As stated in [Blckknght's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568479/10743281) you can do
`lu,area = [], []`

One easy way to check for such problems is to use the `is` keyword. If you type `lu is area` it returns `true` which means they are the same object. But after doing `lu, area = [],[]` you get `false` as return value which indicates they are different objects.